# Logger logs are not showing up in Console and Tomcat logs

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging

Well I have my Tomcat logging configured and I know the properties are being read, because it now genereates the log files according to the name prefix that I specified. Well the problems is that the log files contain all the info that Tomcat itself logs, however it doesn't contain anything from what I try to output in my servlet classes with log.info(...) etc

my logging.properties:

```
    handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINEST
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = GDIA_

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

As you can see it's all set as visible from FINEST, however I don't see any output when i do:

My imports:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

My log variable:

```
private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GenTreeUploader.class.getName());
```

My testing the output:

```
log.severe("GREAT!!!!!!!!!!");
```

I'm running Tomcat 7 in Eclipse. What's interesting is that before I added configuration to tomcat run configuration in eclipse The log output would work fine to console, but whenever I added this:

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp7\conf\logging.properties"
```

I couldn't see any output in console or in the log file. Of course prior to adding this my logging.properties were not to be found...

So any ideas why when I add this configuration I can't see any log output from the application classes when I do "log.severe("GREAT!!!!!!!!!!");"...?